# Google maps is tagging my photos

Tags: google-maps

It appears that Google Maps app I'd tagging my photos with the Camera and displaying an notification even when I am not using the Google Maps app.

[image]

How do I turn this feature off?

Comment: Try photos app > settings> remove geo location as i see no option for settings in camera app

Comment: I never used Photos before. I ran through the setup screens, went into settings and it was adding geo location by default. I turned it off. I'll update this to see if it works and give it a test run.